# rsAccessDenied Report Server

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to get SQL Server Report Manager to work. I'm on windows 7, 64 bit, installed SQL Server Developer with everything included. Every service for MSSQLSERVER is running, IIS is running.

I go to localhost/reportmanager and get a rsAccessDenied message. I've looked at almost every website on this problem, but only found useless answers. Answers like "disable anonymous users in IIS"  (what? No.) and always this thing about doing stuff in report manager. I don't have report manager, I have BIDS.

I try as follows: I'm an administrator, still, I run IE as administrator. I'm prompted for my credentials. I use my credentials for my current account, get rsAccessDenied message.

Comment: Just checking the obvious cases: did you install it with "restrict to HTTPS connections" checked? Are you trying a HTTPS connection now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the Report Manager work under Windows 7, I had to add the registry key:
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy"=dword:00000001

Now, the local administrator can login to localhost/reports.

Also, see:
http://geekswithblogs.net/bjones/archive/2005/05/01/38818.aspx

Answer (score 2):

BIDS is a Visual Studio plug-ins to handle BI projects.
You *do* have Report Manager if you have installed the SSRS services.

First off, have you activated the SSRS install by running the [Report Server Config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156305.aspx) utility?

Second, have you configured [SSRS for WIn Vista/Win 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630430.aspx)?

Also, last time I looked the default is

- /Reports is [Report Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630430.aspx)
- /RportServer is the underlying web service that both Report Manager and VS use

Why do you say "I haven't got Report Manager" and then proceed to launch a URL with "ReportManager" in it?

Comment: Checking out the first two links. The second one is def. yes, the first one I'm reading. The URL was always localhost/reports, did not get a mention of any Report Manager. Anyways, I figured report manager is a program, and I couldn't find it. Always thought you had two options, use report manager or use BIDS.

Comment: I got till step 13 from the tutorial in the second link you provided: In Report Manager, on the Home page, click Folder Settings. I don't have any "Folder Settings"

Comment: If any one is having the same problem and can't find any answers:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630430.aspx

and simultaneously check here:

http://usandriy.spaces.live.com/blog/